# Sql - add row when not existed

Tags: sql, db2

Suppose I have a query that returns result like this:

```
Project Year Type Amt
PJ00001 2012 1    1000
PJ00001 2012 2    1000
PJ00001 2011 1    1000
PJ00002 2012 1    1000
```

What I want: Every Project will have 2 rows of Types for each Year. If the row is not there, add it to the result with Amt = 0.
For example:
- PJ00001 have 2 rows of type 1,2 in 2012 --> OK. But in 2011, it only have 1 row of Type 1 --> We add one row:`PJ00001 2011 2 0`
- PJ00002 have only 1 row of type 1 --> add:`PJ00002 2012 2 0`

Is there a way to easily do it. The only way I know now is to create a view like: PJ_VIEW. And then:

```
SELECT *
FROM PJ_VIEW
UNION ALL
SELECT t.PROJECT, t.YEAR_NO, 1 AS TYPE_NO, 0 AS AMT
FROM PJ_VIEW t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PJ_VIEW t2 WHERE t2.PROJECT = t.PROJECT AND t2.YEAR_NO = t.YEAR_NO AND t2.TYPE_NO = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT t.PROJECT, t.YEAR_NO, 2 AS TYPE_NO, 0 AS AMT
FROM PJ_VIEW t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PJ_VIEW t2 WHERE t2.PROJECT = t.PROJECT AND t2.YEAR_NO = t.YEAR_NO AND t2.TYPE_NO = 2)
```

Comment: Will there be records with Type > 2? or is it always 1 or 1 & 2?

Comment: For my problem, it's only 1 and 2. If the answer can solve for a list, then it's good news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this using DB2 temp tables.  Just replace the content of the table named query with your query.

```
WITH TypeList AS ( 
    SELECT 1 TypeCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
),
query AS (
    SELECT Project, [Year], [Type], Amt FROM yourQuerySource
),
DistinctProjectYears AS (
    SELECT Project, [YEAR]
    FROM query
    GROUP BY Project, [YEAR]
),
Projects AS (
    SELECT Project, [YEAR], [Type] as TypeCode, MAX(Amt) as Amt
    FROM query
    GROUP BY Project, [Year], [Type]
)
SELECT l.TypeCode, py.Project, py.[Year], COALESCE(t.Amt, 0) as Amt
FROM TypeList l CROSS JOIN DistinctProjectYears py
    LEFT JOIN Projects t ON l.TypeCode = t.TypeCode
        AND py.Project = t.Project
        AND py.[Year] = t.[Year]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was looking for something like this but didn't know what to call it.

Answer (score 2):

For a database based solution you need a CROSS JOIN.  The following solution will work for ***n*** project types.  This solution needs a table that contains all the Project Types with a Default Amount.

First create your tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `_projects` (
      `Project`     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `_Year`       INT(4) NOT NULL,
      `ProjectType` INT(1) NOT NULL,
      `ProjectAmt`  INT(11) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE `_projecttypes` (
      `DefaultType` INT(1) NOT NULL,
      `DefaultAmt`  INT(11) DEFAULT 0
    );
```

Insert your project names, years, project types, and amounts:

```
    INSERT INTO `_projects`
    VALUES ('PJ00001', 2012, 1,    1000),
           ('PJ00001', 2012, 2,    1000),
           ('PJ00001', 2011, 1,    1000),
           ('PJ00002', 2012, 1,    1000);
```

Now add your project types with the default value of 0 (zero) or whatever value you need:

```
    INSERT INTO `_projecttypes`
    VALUES (1,0),(2,0);
```

Here is the query that will add default values of 0 into the results for any projects that don't already have a default value.

```
    SELECT 
        IFNULL(`_actualprojects`.`Project`,`der2`.`Project`)          AS `_Project`,
        IFNULL(`_actualprojects`.`_Year`,`der2`.`_Year`)              AS `_Year`,
        IFNULL(`_actualprojects`.`ProjectType`,`der2`.`DefaultType`)  AS `_Type`,
        IFNULL(`_actualprojects`.`ProjectAmt`,`der2`.`DefaultAmt`)    AS `_Amt` 
    FROM 

        (   SELECT DISTINCT `der1`.`DefaultType`,
                            `der1`.`Project`,
                            `der1`.`_Year`,
                            `der1`.`DefaultAmt` 
            FROM 
                (   SELECT *
                    FROM `_projecttypes` CROSS JOIN  `_projects` 
                ) AS `der1`
        ) AS `der2` 

        LEFT JOIN `_projects` AS `_actualprojects` 
            ON `der2`.`Project`       = `_actualprojects`.`Project`
            AND `der2`.`_Year`        = `_actualprojects`.`_Year`
            AND `der2`.`DefaultType`  = `_actualprojects`.`ProjectType`
    ;
```

If you want more Project Types, you can simply add them to the _projecttype table with the default amount, and rereun the above query.

Try it, add these values, then re-run the above query.

```
    INSERT INTO `_projecttypes`
    VALUES (3,0),(4,0);
```

---

I hope this helps you.